# how to place none or null in a blank?

Tags: python

i have few links in which i pass with in pages. now when the href is passing few links doesn't have description. it is fine in the empty place i am trying to place it as "none" or "null" or "0"

```
`for i in range(0,44):
   page_=getcontent(href[i])
   pages=BeautifulSoup(page_.content)

   for i in pages.findAll('p', {"style":"text-align:justify;margin:0px"}):
      if i is None or '':
         description.append("None")
      else:
         description.append(i.text)
      print(description)`
```

how to place it?

Comment: `if i == None or i == '':`. But I'm least sure if that is the issue you are facing.

Comment: # if i is not None and len(i) > 0: #get the content #else: put None